# Why am I getting Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation

Tags: c, exception, visual-studio-2019

I do not understand what is happening.

I made a program to get a char input and output it back.
I receive this exception every time I press enter to input a value into the program:

> Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation. this->_format_it
> was 0x38.

I have tried a large arrangement of inputs and it seems that no matter what I input it will throw this at me.
In fact, This is almost exactly the code my [college gave me](https://ict.senecacollege.ca/%7Eipc144/pages/handouts/h4.html)

Here is the code:

```
// Card Value
// cardValue.c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char rank = 'c';

    printf("Enter the card rank : ");
    scanf("%c", &rank);
    printf(rank);

    return 0;
}
```

Removing the address operator will result in another exception:

> Unhandled exception at 0x79B498F1 (ucrtbased.dll) in Card Decks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000063.

Comment: Which overload of `printf` takes nothing but a `char`? Can you point us to the documentation for that?

Comment: `printf(rank);` is not valid as `printf()` does not accept a single `char` as input.  The 1st parameter must be a `char*`, so perhaps you actually used `printf(&rank);` instead? That would not be valid either since `&rank` is not a valid null-terminated string. You need to use `printf("%c", rank);` instead.

Comment: C does not support overloads anyway.

Comment: ....or exceptions.

Comment: @MartinJames the exception in question is coming from the OS, not from C/C++.  It is an Access Violation exception

Comment: Note that `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` does *not* suppress that warning you should have seen about passing `char` to `printf`.

Comment: Well, OK, is seems that a structured exception escaped the app:(

Comment: About the edit: the codes linked that your college gave you do pass a formatting string to `printf`. Some other languages do support passing any data type to the output function, but C does not.

Comment: @RemyLebeau right - I have never seen a Windows AV error displayed as text - my GUI apps put up a message box when I screw up:)

Comment: About the second edit: you were not asked to remove an address-of operator - that's in the `scanf` function.

Comment: 'This is almost exactly the code....' lol 'almost' - look at the differences:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf(rank);` is incorrect, as `printf()` does not accept a single `char` as input like that.

In C++, this code would not even compile at all.  But in C, the compiler will implicitly convert an integral value into a pointer, and `char` is an integral type.

The read Access Violation error is complaining about memory address `0x38` being read from.  `0x38` is the ASCII code for the character `'8'`, is that the value you are inputting?

The 1st parameter of `printf()` must be a `char*` pointer to a null-terminated format string, eg:

```c
printf("%c", rank);
```

All of the examples in the [code your college gave you](https://ict.senecacollege.ca/%7Eipc144/pages/handouts/h4.html) are in this similar form.

---

If you remove the `&` on the `scanf("%c", &rank)` call (why?), you get an Access Violation writing to memory address `0x63`, because the *value* of `rank` gets implicitly converted as-is to a pointer.  `0x63` is the ASCII code for the character `'c'`, which is what you are initializing `rank` to.

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot. I replaced it with " printf("%c",rank); " and got it fixed

Answer (score 4):

`printf()`'s first argument must be a pointer to a format string, not a char.  You could do

```cpp
printf("%c", rank);
```

Comment: That gives me an entirely different error.

Comment: Unhandled exception at 0x79B498F1 (ucrtbased.dll) in Card Decks.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000063.

Comment: @CarsonFujita-Turnbull Because you "removed the address-of operator" without being advised to and without any reason to do so